# On vacuum energy in a de Sitter universe?

Tags: entropy, vacuum, event-horizon, cosmological-constant, poincare-recurrence

I have a couple of questions about de Sitter cosmological horizons. Initially I made a single post containing the two questions, but after some suggestions, I asked them in two separate posts. This one is about vacuum energy in a de Sitter universe:

In this video by Leonard Susskind (https://youtu.be/n7eW-xPEvoQ?t=2324) he explains the concept of the Poincaré recurrence using particles and the cosmological horizon.

Susskind says that one escape to the recurrence problem is the decay of the cosmological constant in form of a false vacuum decay. However, since an expanding true vacuum bubble would expand at light speed and in an accelerating expanding universe the distances between galaxies will eventually expand to the point where light cannot overtake this expansion, wouldn't spacetime expansion outpace the nucleation and expansion of these bubbles? Then, could there be regions that would not be affected by these bubbles and their expansion?

Comment: You are grappling with the ideas that lead to the concept of [eternal inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_inflation).

Comment: @Andrew that's interesting, altough these true vacuum bubbles would expand at lightspeed, while inflation as far as I know, since it is about the expansion of spacetime wouldn't have this limit, right?

Comment: Yeah so it's the same idea but applied in a different context. In inflation, the Universe is expanding exponentially and the bubbles of true vacuum lower the vacuum energy and take you out of the inflationary phase. However, the exponential inflation is so fast that the true vacuum bubbles don't expand to fill the whole space, so there are always places where inflation is going on. It's the same basic idea you are asking about, just at a different scale. Vacuum bubbles aren't enough to end de Sitter expansion everywhere.